# How to pass user defined type parameter to the stored procedure using SqlDataSource

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sqldatasource

We have user defined type in our SQL Server database defined as shown here:

```
CREATE TYPE Integer_List_tblType_InMemory 
     AS TABLE 
        ( 
            RecordId BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED
        ) WITH (MEMORY_OPTIMIZED = ON)
```

The procedure definition:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GET_ListOfOrders 
    (@P_ContactId BIGINT,
     @P_ContactGroupIds Integer_List_tblType_InMemory READONLY,
     @P_ProductIds Integer_List_tblType_InMemory READONLY,
     @P_SearchText NVARCHAR(150),
     @P_CurrentPageIndex BIGINT NULL,
     @P_PageSize BIGINT NULL)
```

Frontend code:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="sdsOrders"        
    SelectCommand="GET_ListOfOrders" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"
    ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="P_ContactId" QueryStringField="ContractId" DbType="Int64" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtDocumentSearch" PropertyName="Text" Name="P_SearchText" />
        <asp:SessionParameter SessionField="ContactGroupIds" Name="P_ContactGroupIds" />
        <asp:SessionParameter SessionField="ProductIds " Name="P_ProductIds" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

The session hold data tables with unique list of Ids. The values are not getting passed to the procedure. I tried all possible combination.

What am I missing?

If not possible to pass using the `SqlDataSource`, what is the alternative?

Comment: **Note**: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Thanks @marc_s for the suggestion, will take a note of it and implement accordingly